# PKCS#11: C_Decrypt retured CKR_OPERATION_NOT_INITIALIZED

Tags: smartcard, pkcs#11

I have been trying to decrypt a file with a smart card but I get weird message.

I am using PKCS11Interop to invoke C_Decrypt in the dll file that uses pkcs11.h
to communicate with smart cards.

This is the code:

```
public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] encData)
    {
        byte[] decrypt = null;

        using (Session session = _slot.OpenSession(SessionType.ReadOnly))
        using (Mechanism mechanism = new Mechanism(CKM.CKM_RSA_PKCS))
        {
            decrypt = session.Decrypt(mechanism, _privateKeyHandle, encData);
        }

        return decrypt;
    }
```

The weird thing is, when I use [Yubico smart card](https://www.yubico.com/product/yubikey-5-nfc/#yubikey-5-nfc) with opensc-pkcs11.dll, it works fine. When I use [HSID5000](https://www.parsec.co.za/hsid-5000-1/) with hsid-pkcs11.dll it fails with message "C_Decrypt returned CKR_OPERATION_NOT_INITIALIZED"

When I use the same smart card (HSID5000) but in pkcs11-tool instead of Pkcs11Interop, it works:

```
pkcs11-tool --id 01 --decrypt -p ******** -m RSA-PKCS --module hsid-pkcs11.dll --input-file input.enc
```

Here is the pkcs11-logger file generated with Pkcs11Interop in both scenarios (Opensc smart card and HSID smart card)

Yubico opensc smart card log file:

```
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 : Calling C_Decrypt
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 : Input
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  hSession: 35424832
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  pEncryptedData: 0000000002E334C0
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  *pEncryptedData: HEX(793...D99)
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  ulEncryptedDataLen: 256
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  pData: 0000000002E346E0
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  pulDataLen: 000000000042EB48
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  *pulDataLen: 7
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 : Output
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  pData: 0000000002E346E0
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  pulDataLen: 000000000042EB48
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  *pData: HEX(730D0A730D0A73)
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 :  *pulDataLen: 7
0x00000b04 : 0x00000734 : Returning 0 (CKR_OK)
```

HSID smart card log file:

```
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 : Calling C_Decrypt
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 : Input
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 :  hSession: 12274064
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 :  pEncryptedData: 0000000002E6A300
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 :  *pEncryptedData: HEX(49B....527)
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 :  ulEncryptedDataLen: 256
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 :  pData: 0000000002E6B520
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 :  pulDataLen: 00000000004AE938
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 :  *pulDataLen: 256
0x00001b90 : 0x00000d94 : Returning 145 (CKR_OPERATION_NOT_INITIALIZED)
```

Can someone help me with this?

### Update #1:

The Full log file for the hsid-pkcs11.dll is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1b5t7aGfXd1YsvpO9do7QZraFRFW76Ejz)

### Update #2: (Solution!)

After the remarkable comment from jariq, the HSID token doesn't like multiple calls to C_Decrypt, so I used his wrapper but instead of using the HighLevel library, I used the Lowlevel one and called C_Decrypt only once. And it worked!

Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Can you please post full logs generated with hsid-pkcs11.dll? Single failing call is not sufficient for analysis.

Comment: Just attached a link to the full log file. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you also post a full log for `pkcs11-tool`, please.

Comment: I didn't know how to enforce logger with pkcs11-tool. I tried -v but didn't work.

Comment: You can use parameter `--module pkcs11-logger.dll` instead of `--module hsid-pkcs11.dll`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When executed with `--decrypt` argument `pkcs11-tool` calls (see [source code](https://github.com/OpenSC/OpenSC/blob/0.19.0/src/tools/pkcs11-tool.c#L1951-L1960)) following PKCS#11 functions:

- `C_DecryptInit` to initialize operation
- `C_Decrypt` with allocated output buffer to receive the decrypted data

Pkcs11Interop calls (see [source code](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/blob/4.0.0/src/Pkcs11Interop/Pkcs11Interop/HighLevelAPI41/Session.cs#L854-L866)) following PKCS#11 functions in implementation of `session.Decrypt()`:

- `C_DecryptInit` to initialize operation
- `C_Decrypt` without allocated output buffer to determine length of decrypted data
- `C_Decrypt` with allocated output buffer to receive the decrypted data

It seems that `hsid-pkcs11.dll` does not like it when application calls `C_Decrypt` twice as Pkcs11Interop does. However calling `C_Decrypt` twice is completely fine and this technique is described in chapter 11.2 of [PKCS#11 v2.20 specification](https://github.com/Pkcs11Interop/PKCS11-SPECS/blob/master/v2.20/pkcs-11v2-20.pdf?raw=true).

Exactly the same specification states on page 145 that:

> `C_Decrypt` uses the convention described in Section 11.2 on producing output.

IMO you need to contact vendor of your unmanaged PKCS#11 library and ask him for fix or at least explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Your Answer makes sense. I will contact them to explain why they don't allow this scenario. Appreciate your effort.